# VBA Scraping Data From Multiple Websites

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to scrape commodity/stock prices from multiple pages on investing.com and insert them into an excel spreadsheet.

The following code is what I have working to do a single price, in this example gold:

```
Sub Extractdatafromwebsite()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "http://uk.investing.com/commodities/gold"

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.READYSTATE = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.document

output = doc.GetElementById("last_last").innerText
Range("A1").Value = output

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

However I need data from multiple sites to get different prices, all at the same time.

I tried elaborating on the code I have that is working, the following example is what I tried to display the price of gold and silver, however it only displayed the gold price in cells A1 & A2:

```
Sub Extractdatafromwebsite()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "http://uk.investing.com/commodities/gold"

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.READYSTATE = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.document

output = doc.GetElementById("last_last").innerText
Range("A1").Value = output

ie.Quit

ie.navigate "http://uk.investing.com/commodities/silver"

Set doc = ie.document

output = doc.GetElementById("last_last").innerText
Range("A2").Value = output

ie.Quit


End Sub
```

Please could somebody help me figure out how to get this to work for multiple pages? I have tried searching however have not come up with anything that suits my needs.

Also is it possible to get something to pop up saying something like "Waiting...." whilst the data is being collected?

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, you probably shouldn't `Quit` the `ie` instance before the second `Navigate`, and secondly, you will likely need to repeat the `Do..Loop Until` to allow the browser time to finish loading the page...

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly, I did have the loop in originally but it wasnt working, removed the quit ie and that sorted it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using READYSTATE is not reliable in the sense that the document hasn't fully loaded sometimes - or at least the object model hasn't loaded.

So I typically add a sleep command and Doevents before trying to access the new doc object

This should work for you (and as @Dave says, you don't need to use `IE.Quit`)

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

    Sub Extractdatafromwebsite()

        Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument        

        ie.Visible = False
        ie.Navigate "http://uk.investing.com/commodities/gold"
        Do
            Sleep 500
            DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4 ' READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Sleep 500

        Set doc = ie.Document

        output = doc.GetElementById("last_last").innerText
        Range("A1").Value = output

        ie.Navigate "http://uk.investing.com/commodities/silver"

        Do
            Sleep 500
            DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4 ' READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Sleep 500

        Set doc = ie.Document

        output = doc.GetElementById("last_last").innerText
        Range("A2").Value = output

        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: You can add your `Range("A1").Value = output` and `Range("A2").Value = output` commands back in

Comment: Added Win32 API Sleep function to top of the code, just in case you didn't have that handy. Make sure to put it at the very top of your module above all constants and subroutines. Let me know if that does the jobe for you.